# IIS - How to have a separate SSL for an application under the Default Website

Tags: iis, ssl, asp.net

We are hosting multiple ASP.Net applications on an IIS web server. All the applications are under the same 'Default Web Site' parent. Most of them have their separate application pool.

[image: Webserver]

The default website is bounded to a SSL certificate and all applications use the same certificate. Now, I have to provide a different SSL to one of the applications. My questions are:

1. Is it possible for the application under 'Default Web Site' to have a different binding for SSL?
2. If not, what are some of the options?

Answer (score 0):

If your IIS is version 8.0 or higher (Windows Server 2012 or newer), it supports an extension to the TLS protocol called [SNI (Server Name Indication)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Here are some IIS specific [instructions](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability) on using it.

If you have anything earlier than IIS 8.0, you will either need to get a re-issued certificate that contains all of the names you need in it using the [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) field.  Or you will need to host the alternate certificate in a new website bound to a different IP:port combination.

Comment: We are using Server 2012 with IIS8.